# No module named pip.req, when install tweepy

Tags: python, pip, tweepy

I'm trying to install tweepy library, I have tried the solution for the questions that are similar to this, but nothing work. please help

```
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 64, in <lambda>
        {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
      File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named pip.req
```

Comment: what is the output of `pip --version`?

Comment: pip 7.1.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Comment: Can you show the commands you use to instally `tweepy`?

Comment: sudo easy_install-2.6 tweepy
oooh, now i understood. it must be sudo easy_install-2.7 tweepy. Sorry and thank you :D